# Is there a way to display a matrix of chars as an image?

Tags: c++, matrix

I should open with the fact that I am very new to c++.

I am attempting to display a constantly updating 20x20 matrix of chars. Currently, I am displaying the the matrix using for loops as cout's (code below) but that is incredibly flickery- I'm looking for something smoother.

Is there a way to convert this char matrix into an image and display that?

This is my first question here, so I apologize if I did something wrong!

Code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int randInt;

    //Initialize matrix and location
    int matrix[20][20];
    int location[2] = {0,0};
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
            for (int j=0; j<20; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
            }
    }


    //move the X around
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        cout << string(50, '\n');
        //Change the X's location
        randInt = rand() % 4;
        switch (randInt)
        {
            case 0:
                if(location[1] > 0)
                    location[1] = location[1]-1;
                break;
            case 1:
                if(location[0] < 20)
                    location[0] = location[0]+1;
                break;
            case 2:
                if(location[1] < 20)
                    location[1] = location[1]+1;
                break;
            case 3:
                if(location[0] > 0)
                    location[0] = location[0]-1;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Switch statement problem";
        }
        //Display the matrix
        for (int x=0; x<20; x++)
        {
            for (int y=0; y<20; y++)
            {
                if(x==location[0] && y==location[1])
                    cout << "X";
                else
                    cout << matrix[x][y];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you're using unix, look into curses

Comment: `system("pause");` indicates Windows and Visual Studio. Try Ctrl-F5 instead of the call to pause.

Comment: Are you trying to display the entries of the matrix in an image (i.e. you get to see the actual numbers) or are you just trying to get a sense of what is in the matrix by color coding the numbers (i.e. 0 is pure black and 255 is pure white)? If it is the latter, an image processing library such as OpenCV might be useful.

Comment: Actual numbers. But thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rename the `location[2]` to something like `struct { int x,y; } location for readability.

Then you can build an array of characters in RAM and put out it at once.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char matrix[20][20];
    char image[21][21];
    struct { int x, y; } location;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    location.x = 7;
    location.y = 3;

    // fill the matrix
    for (x = 0; x < 20; ++x)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < 20; ++y)
        {
            matrix[y][x] = 'a' + x + y;
        }
    }

    // prepare the image
    y = 0;

    while (y < 20)
    {
        memcpy(image[y], matrix[y], 20);
        image[y][20] = '\n';
        ++y;
    }

    // add the cross
    image[location.y][location.x] = 'X';
    image[20][0] = '\0';

    // use the image        
    puts((char*)image);
}
```

Please add you random functionality as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the char to a image and see the color means, write the char value as pixel in simple pgm format.

Write a file in this sample format

```
P2
# feep.pgm
24 7
15
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  3  3  3  3  0  0  7  7  7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11  0  0 15 15 15 15  0
0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0 15  0
0  3  3  3  0  0  0  7  7  7  0  0  0 11 11 11  0  0  0 15 15 15 15  0
0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0  0  0
0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  7  7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11  0  0 15  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

check this link http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html for pgm format